# Impossible to print FindFirstFile WIN32_FIND_DATA structure properties with MASM

Tags: assembly, masm, cpu-registers

I want to reproduce the behaviour of the C++ code just below in MASM :

C++ code :

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <strsafe.h>

int                     _tmain(int ac, TCHAR **av)
{
    HANDLE              hFile;
    WIN32_FIND_DATA     findFileData;
    BOOL                retFindNextFile;

    if ((hFile = FindFirstFile(TEXT("C:\\Users\\Bloodsucker94\\Desktop\\TestFolder\\*.txt"), &findFileData)) == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    else {
        do {
            _tprintf(TEXT("%s\n"), findFileData.cFileName);
            retFindNextFile = FindNextFile(hFile, &findFileData);

        } while (retFindNextFile == TRUE);
    }
    getchar();
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

And the MASM code :

```
.386
.model                          flat, stdcall
option                          casemap :none

include                         \masm32\include\windows.inc
include                         \masm32\include\kernel32.inc
include                         \masm32\include\masm32.inc
include                         \masm32\include\masm32rt.inc
includelib                      \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib
includelib                      \masm32\lib\masm32.lib
include                         \masm32\include\msvcrt.inc
includelib                      \masm32\lib\msvcrt.lib

.data

FolderPath                      BYTE                        "C:\Users\Bloodsucker94\Desktop\TestASM\*.txt", 0
FindFirstFileError              BYTE                        "FindFirstFile() failed with code %d", 0
FindFirstFileSuccess            BYTE                        "First file found with success - hfile=%d", 0
PrintStructAddr                 BYTE                        "addr=Ox%08X", 0
PrintFileName                   BYTE                        "%s", 0

.data?

hFile                           HANDLE                      ?
findFileData                    WIN32_FIND_DATA             <>
retFindNextFile                 BOOL                        ?
ErrorCode                       DWORD                       ?

.code
start:

    ;--------------------------------------------------------

    invoke  FindFirstFile,      ADDR FolderPath,            \
                                ADDR findFileData

    mov     hFile,              eax

    .IF hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE
        invoke  GetLastError
        mov     ErrorCode,      eax
        invoke  crt_printf,     ADDR FindFirstFileError,    \
                                ErrorCode
        jmp                     _quit                                
    .ENDIF

    ;--------------------------------------------------------

    mov     ebx,                OFFSET findFileData
    mov     al,                 [ebx].WIN32_FIND_DATA.cFileName

    print   str$(findFileData.cFileName)
    ;print  str$([ebx].WIN32_FIND_DATA.cFileName)
    ;print  str$(al)

    ;INVOKE crt_printf,         ADDR PrintFileName,         \
    ;                           findFileData.cFileName

    ;--------------------------------------------------------

_quit:
    invoke  ExitProcess,        0

end start
```

For the moment, as you can see, I just want to print the first file name in my directory 'TestASM'. At the execution FindFirstFile() seems to be well executed and the hFile handle seems to be correct too. However I don't understand why all my print calls lead to a message box displaying an error message. I think it's a segmentation fault. But I have respected the C++ code behaviour. I tried several code combinations in vain.

Does anyone can help me ?

Comment: I tried a strange experience. I replace my console logs by a window log (MessageBox) and it works. Why my console logs failed ? However, it's the same data!

Answer (score 1):

You should declare `printf PROTO C :VARARG;`

Comment: The function is already defined : error A2005: symbol redefinition : printf. it's the same thing with crt_printf

Comment: Maybe the problem is cFileName is type TCHAR* and printf does work in C++ correctly with that type. However the good function is _tprintf. But I didn't found a equivalent for this function in MASM. Do you have an idea ? Thanks again

Comment: As debug hint, can you change your code to print some integer and not a string

Comment: Yes natives types (int, char*, double, etc) work perfectly. It's just Windows types (TCHAR* here) which does not work. I need a special function to print Windows types like TCHAR*. In my C++ code I use _tprintf. If I a use a simple printf the result printed is not correct. MessageBox print the good result because it integrates a special Windows API function within. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just to make sure : you say that if you use printf in your code (I mean the C++ one) the print result is messed up ?

Comment: OK ! so I think we face issue of mixing b/n wide characters and MBCS (ASCII ones..) please set your application to use the ASCII version FindFirstFileA , by doing so "classic" printf will work

Answer (score 0):

> I replace my console logs by a window log (MessageBox) and it works. Why my console logs failed ? However, it's the same data!

You're using `str$` incorrectly. If you look at its definition (masm32\macros\macros.asm) you'll see that what it does is take a `DWORD`-sized integer, create a string representation of that integer (e.g. 123 -> "123") using `dwtoa`, and return the address of the string.

Since you're trying to print something that already is a string the correct way to do it would be:

```
print   ADDR findFileData.cFileName
```

As for the crashes you're seeing - what will happen with your current code (`print   str$(findFileData.cFileName)`) is that `str$` will do the following:

```
invoke dwtoa,findFileData.cFileName,ADDR rvstring
```

When MASM expands this `invoke` macro and doesn't find an `ADDR` operator in front of an argument it will pass that argument *by value*. In this case it will assume that you're trying to pass the first element of `findFileData.cFileName`, which is a `BYTE` (or `WORD` if you're using the wide-string version).
So in effect, this is what actually will be pushed onto the stack as the first argument:

```
mov al,findFileData.cFileName  ; al is set to the first character in the string
movzx ax,al
push ax   ; can't push bytes on x86 so the byte is extended to a word
```

Since `dwtoa` expects a `DWORD` as the first argument and you're passing a `WORD` you'll get an unbalanced stack when returning from `dwtoa`, which can lead to all sorts of undesired behavior (in this case a crash).

Answer (score 0):

This works no problem.

```
mov     ebx,                OFFSET findFileData
lea     eax,                 [ebx].WIN32_FIND_DATA.cFileName

print   eax
```

So does this:

```
INVOKE crt_printf,         ADDR PrintFileName,         \
                           offset findFileData.cFileName
```

See the differences between this code and yours?  You need to pass the address of the strings.  We do that for the fist one with `lea` and use offset for the `printf`